# Json a Objeto, usando api rest

Tags: java, api

Estoy realizando un programa en java utilizando api rest para conectarme y obtener los datos de la base de dato.

Por ahora tengo la siguientes clases: [image]
Y el json correspondiente a la información de los usuarios son:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "ejemplo",
    "email": "Ejemplo1@gmail.com"
}
```

¿Como puedo pasar la información de este usuario a Tipo “User” para poder acceder a sus correspondientes metodos `getEmail()` y `getNombre()`?

Answer (score 1):

No se si exista una libreria mas "actual" respecto a esto, pero conozco `Gson`, que basicamente deberias crear tu clase `Usuario`

```
public class Usuario {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String email;
}
```

Crear los metodos `get` y `set` y de donde obtengas el json hacer:

```
Usuario usuario = new Gson().fromJson(tu_json, Usuario.class);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, y ¿Esta manera es la que se suele utilizar profesionalmente o hay una mejor manera de hacerlo?

Comment: La verdad, es que no creo que exista una manera "profesional" de siempre hacer las cosas, pero solo googleando `Gson` encontraras mucha información

Comment: Perdón, me refería la manera mas utilizada y consolidada

Answer (score 0):

Para estos casos, lo mas ideal es usar [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), el cual es uno de los mas utilizados.